# How to customize the loading screen in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, loading, qsplashscreen

I need to create a customized and animated loading screen in Qt, and I don't need a progress bar.

I want to do something like this:

[image]

Anyone knows how can I do that?

Can I use, for example, QSplashScreen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [QMovie](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html) to load an animation`

```
QMovie * movie = new QMovie("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdYAH.gif");
```

You can either load the movie directly to a label, hide and show it when necessary

```
QLabel label;
label.setMovie(movie);
movie->start();
```

Or read the frames of the movie to set splash screen pixmap continuously

```
connect(movie, SIGNAL(frameChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setSplashScreenPixmap(int)));
movie->start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I am looking for.